# query a single object using AngularJS, Morphia, MongoDB and Java

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, rest, morphia

I'm trying to figure out how to query a single object in a collection. 
Basically I have a list of records, when I click on a record I should call a rest service using the id based on which row has been clicked. The problem is that when I retrieve the list using angularjs in this way

```
.controller('ViewEmployeesControllerRest',function ($scope, $routeParams, EmplServ) {
    EmplServ.query(function(data) {
        $scope.employee = data;
});})
```

the server returns an array of employees with an ObjectId a bit weird:

```
[ { "id": { "_time": 1405270918, "_machine": 1152262501, "_inc": 19814452, "_new": false }, "address1": "test", "firstName": "test1", "gender": "male", "lastName": "test1ciaociao", "maidenName": "hello" ...
```

How can I use an object with the ObjectId in that way? Because after I call the service I want to edit the employee and call the PUT service from the controller passing the ObjectId again.

Comment: Seems `data[0].id` to me. But surly I've never seen something called id that so none idish...

Comment: What is the Morphia query (the Angular part is just a REST call against a custom Java implementation, right?), what are you getting now, what do you actually want to get?

Comment: The Morphia query is just a employee.find() and it will return all the employees. 
The ObjectId is an object like  "id": { "_time": 1405270918, "_machine": 1152262501, "_inc": 19814452, "_new": false }
It's not just a String.

Comment: Btw I'm using Gson to convert the Employees into json objects

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution overriding the JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer:

```
public class ObjectIdGsonAdapter implements JsonSerializer<ObjectId>, JsonDeserializer<ObjectId> {

@Override
public ObjectId deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT  ,
                            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return new ObjectId(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
}

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(ObjectId src, Type typeOfSrc,
                             JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
}
```

}